# jquery plugins working with different jquery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-versions

i got plugins using 3 different versions of jQuery on my site "1.7.1" "1.5.2" and "1.3.2". Got first 2 on my main page and theyre working just fine, but when i enter a site that uses the third one aswell, addons based on 1.7.1 and 1.5.2 stop working.

I did try adding jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true); script, and then switching every $ in third app to jq132, but that doesnt seem to work. Any tips?

**EDIT:** i managed to cut out 1.5.2 and 1.3.2 versions, thanks for tips

Comment: Here's a tip: Use one version of jquery.

Comment: Just curious: Why do you have 3 different versions of jQuery on the same page?

Comment: because i got 3 js apps that use different versions if jQuery, how could i use just one version in this case?

Comment: @Ates Goral, yea true, I guess when I go to the gas station and fill up I use a little from 87, a little from 89 and top it off with some 92.

Comment: USe the latest version. Its backward compatible. Better still upgrade  your js plugins. Here, we crib about including as little code as possible to speed things up and you're using 3 different versions of jquery. The footprint will be enormous

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** try editing each version of jQuery to change the namespace variable for each version if you ***really*** need all three versions (which you really don't, btw).

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Use the correct document accordingly with window argument (sandbox)
var document = window.document,
    navigator = window.navigator,
    location = window.location;

var jQuery132 = (function() {

// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
```

and then in your $(document).ready():

```
jQuery132(document).ready(function($132) {
   // code goes here
});
```

and your `$` would be replaced with `$132` for your 1.3.2 version and so on.

Btw, this is a **really bad** idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably doing wrong is not calling `$.noConflict` right after including a version of jQuery. After every jQuery include tag, there needs to be `<script>` tag with `$.noConflict` for that version of jQuery.

See: [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)